# Getting real time traffic data from Google maps or any map library

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to extract traffic data from google maps or yandex map or etc..

I have a map on my Android app, users can select start and finish points for travel.
And then I calculate minimum road distance(not as the crow flies), and an algorithm runs after this process. This algorithm needs real time traffic data.

Another option is assumption in traffic(at rush hours, I can give a rate about traffic). If I couldn't find a workaround, I will use this option.

Is there any available api to figure out this issue..

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As now the best you can do using Android Maps API is to display traffic layer using `map.setTrafficEnabled(true)`. Unsure how to extract the traffic data.

Comment: That data is not available from Google except via the traffic layer.